# Tensorflow Optimizing multiply then add

Tags: tensorflow, linear-algebra

It is common in linear algebra to optimize the common operation of multiply then add by appending a dummy constant dimension to the input, then turning the whole into a single multiply ( `Wx + b => W'x'`).

Is there any benefit to doing this in Tensorflow, or will it optimize that anyway (e.g. `tf.matmul(...) + b` vs. `tf.matmul(...)`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are speaking about is not an optimization which increases speed, reduces memory. It is just a way to shorten the mathematical expression.

- there is no reduction in memory because instead of having a vector `b` you just prepend/append your matrix with a column of the same size of `b`.
- even if you will not count the number of operations needed to append/prepend the matrix W with a column, your matrix multiplication will perform more operations. You trade adding `n` elements `b_i` if you just add a vector to adding `n` elements calculated as `c_i * x_i`.

There is no benefit (in terms of speed/memory) of doing this in TF and no, TF does not optimize it by itself.

If it is easier for you to read and understand what is going on there, you are free write it in that way.

Comment: Can you explain why you argue that this doesn't increase speed or reduce memory? I always thought it did.

Comment: I would be also curious to hear your justification why it should improve anything. I added my justifications in the answer